# Android Studio 1.3 : Test Module is not coming in Module window

Tags: android, testing, android-studio

I update android studio in 1.3.2. and gradle plugin is also 1.3.0
but on clicking file -> New -> Module. Window is opening but the recent update in android studio test module is not showing

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but you can create it manually

Comment: Manually How? @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: Check the updated answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create manually a structure like

```
root
  app
    build.gradle
  testmodule
    build.gradle
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
```

Create a folder, for example `testmodule`.

In **testmodule** create:

```
   testmodule
       build.gradle
       src
         main
            java
              com.mycompany.package.test
```

In `testmodule.build.gradle` you can do something like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.test' 

android {
    compileSdkVersion XX
    buildToolsVersion = '23.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion ...
        targetSdkVersion ..
        // The package name of the test app
        testApplicationId 'com.mycompany.package.test'
        // The Instrumentation test runner used to run tests.
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    // Set the target app project. The module specified here should contain the production code
    // test should run against.
    targetProjectPath ':app'
    targetVariant 'flavor1Debug'
}

dependencies {
    // Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules and hamcrest matchers
    compile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    compile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
}
```

In `settings.gradle` add the module.

```
include ':app'
include ':testmodule'
```

Make sure to use the plugin 1.3 and gradle 2.5

In your top-level `build.gradle`

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

In your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip
```